# Natural logs with L'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Given $$\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-2x)^\frac{1}{x} $$ I know that you take the natural log $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(e^x-2x) $$ which is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(e^x-2x)}{x} $$ but what is after this?

Comment: You have just taken the natural log. Now, Hopital rule requires that you differentiate numerator and denominator...

Answer (score 1):

Now since the limit is of $0/0$ form we can apply L'Hopital's rule. So differentiate numerator and denominator, we get

$\lim_{x \to 0}(e^x-2)/(e^x-2x)=-1$.

Now the real limit comes out to be $e^{-1}$.

Comment: I need to take a break my God

Comment: Don't worry it happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-2x)^{1/x}\neq \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x}\ln(e^x-2x)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-2x)^{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0} e^{\ln{(e^x-2x)}/x}=$$

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (e^x-2x)}x\right)$$
Now we can apply L'Hospital Rule, which means differentiating both numerator and denominator
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-2}{e^x-2x}\right)=e^{-1}=\frac1e$$

Answer (score 0):

For the form of limit 1^(infinity), 
lim f(x)^g(x) = e^ lim [{f(x) - 1}•g(x)]
Using Maclaurin expansion, you will get e^(-x/x) which is e^-1

e^x = 1 + x/1! + (x^2)/2! + (x^3)/3! ...